# Wrong functional sorting in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

So I want to sort an array by different criteria, but here comes the problem, when both items have the same value, I'd like to order it for the name. Let me explain it with an example:
I have this:

Ohio 49

Wisconsin 46

Kentucky 46

This would be my data structure:

```
const int US_STATES = 51;
const int MAX_INFO = 5;

struct Info{
    double values;
    int units, shipments;
};

typedef Info TaulaQuarters[MAX_INFO];   //Where TaulaQuarters[0] és el total i TaulaQUarters[1..4] son els trimestres

struct Estat{
    string stateName,code;
    int population;
    TaulaQuarters taulaQuarters;
    int totalPopulation;
};

typedef Estat TaulaEstats[US_STATES];
```

So, Wisconsin and Kentucky have the same value, But I'd like to have Wisconsin under Kentucky, because Kentucky is greater than Wisconsin alphabetically.
Let me show you my main sorting actions:

```
bool esMajor (double n1, double n2, string nom1, string nom2, char criteri)
{
    //pre:
    //lpost:
        int enter1 = int(n1);
        int enter2 = int(n2);

        bool hoEs = false;
        if (criteri == 'v'){
            if (n1 > n2) hoEs = true;
            else if (n1 == n2){
                if (nom1 > nom2) hoEs = true;
            }
        }
        else if (criteri == 'u' or criteri == 's'){
            if (enter1 > enter2) hoEs = true;
            else if (enter1 == enter2){
                if (nom1 < nom2) hoEs = true;
            }
        }
        else if (criteri == 'n'){
            if (nom1 < nom2) hoEs = true;
        }
        //else if ()
        return hoEs;
}
void ordena (TaulaEstats taulaEstats, char criteri)
{
    //Pre:
    //post:
        //----Intializing----
        Estat aux; aux.code = "--"; aux.population = 0; aux.stateName = "--"; aux.totalPopulation = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
            aux.taulaQuarters[x].shipments = 0; aux.taulaQuarters[x].units = 0; aux.taulaQuarters[x].values = 0;
        }
        //-------END---------
        for (int i = 0; i < int(US_STATES);i++){
            int j = i;
            //if (criteri == 'v'){
                while (j > 0 and esMajor(taulaEstats[j].taulaQuarters[0].values,taulaEstats[j-1].taulaQuarters[0].values,taulaEstats[j].stateName, taulaEstats[j-1].stateName, criteri)){
                    aux = taulaEstats[j-1];
                    taulaEstats[j-1] = taulaEstats[j];
                    taulaEstats[j]= aux;
                    j--;
                }
            }
}
```

Where `esMajor`will tell me depending of the criteria, if the first number is greater than the second one, and in case of equal, will tell me if the first name is greater than the second one.
And `ordena` is just the algorithm I have to sort my array.

Thanks for your help and happy holidays!!

(Sorry for my English though).

Answer (score 0):

If this is C++, you should encapsulate the number and the name in your struct and overload the comparison operators for your class. like this:

```
struct StateInfo
{
    std::string stateName; 
    int stateNumber;

public:
    StateInfo() : stateName("DEFAULTNAME"),stateNumber(0){}

    StateInfo(std::string name, int, number): stateName(name),stateNumber(number){}


    bool operator< (const StateInfo& rhs)
    {

        if( rhs.stateNumber==this->stateNumber) 
        {
            return rhs.stateName< this->stateName; //if numbers are equal compare by name
        } 
        return rhs.stateNumber<this->stateNumber; 
    } 

    //overload other operators as necessary


}
```

now you can use `std::sort` from `#include <algorithm>`  to sort all of your objects that you put in a container such as `std::vector`.

the gist of the solution is you are letting std::sort know how to compare 2 different instances of your struct. when std::sort knows this, it can do the sorting for you.

going the array route is very messy and not recommended.

if you are interested in making your own sorting algorithm or practicing insertion sort, merge sort, quicksort, etc. then you can still use the overloaded operators > < == <= and >=  to write your own sorting algorithm.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the sort commands, and had to develop it on my own, and I'm not working with objects yet, so I kinda have no idea of what you're talking about :(

Comment: you have a struct definition in your code. you ARE working with objects

Answer (score 0):

If both of the numbers are same you just have to take their names and then apply this algorithm

```
if(name1[0]>name2[0]){
    //Name1 is alphabetically greater place it first in the queue
}
else if(name1[0]<name2[0]){
    //Name2 is alphabetically greater place it first in the queue
}
else{
    //Both are equal. Do what you want.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit of a minefield, but you can achieve what you want with something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>     // std::pair
#include <algorithm> // std::sort
#include <iterator>  // std::begin, std::end
#include <iostream>

using StateInfo   = std::pair<int, std::string>;
using CountryInfo = std::vector<StateInfo>;

int main()
{
    CountryInfo usa_info {{49, "Ohio"}, {46, "Wisconsin"}, {46, "Kentucky"}};

    std::sort(std::begin(usa_info), std::end(usa_info));

    for (const auto& d : usa_info) std::cout << d.second << " " << d.first << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This works because `std::pair` already overloads `operator<` and sorts by the first, and then then second element. If you don't want to use `std::pair`, you can overload `operator<` for your own class.

Comment: I can't use the algorithm from the library, I have to make it on my own :s, and it doesn't work, I kinda want to kill myself now lmaokai